# Zend DB and encoding

Tags: php, zend-framework, encoding, utf-8, zend-db

I have just encountered something rather strange, I use the Zend Framework 1.10 with the Zend_Db_Table module to read some data from a databse. The database itself, the table and the fields in question all have their collation set to "utf8_general_ci" and all special chars appear correctly formatted in the DB when checked with phpMyAdmin. Also, saving with Zend_Db_Table works just fine, yet when I read the data and just echo it to my browser it is returned as ISO-8859-1, not as UTF8. I noticed the same thing when trying to use json_encode (which only works with UTF8 strings as input) on a value returned from the DB.

How can I set that Zend_Db_Table/Zend_Db_Row should always work with UTF8 and return me an UTF8 value? I have not set anything regarding encoding in my app yet.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just note. In my case this one helped:

```
    $this->db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
        'host'     => $config['db_hostname'],
        'username' => $config['db_username'],
        'password' => $config['db_password'],
        'dbname'   => $config['db_database'],
        'charset'  => 'utf8'
    ));
```

Comment: This didn't for for me, however as @robertbasic commented below "resources.db.params.charset = utf8" in the app ini fixed the problem.

Comment: Making this the accepted answer since the upvotes clearly favor this solution (along with @robertbasic's comment)

Answer (score 5):

```
resources.db.params.charset = utf8
```

like robertbasic said.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just found the solution, try to do this:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database); // Setting up the DB
$db->query("SET NAMES 'utf8';");           // That's the magic line I was missing
```

Hope this helps somebody else at some point :)

Comment: it's easier just to add: `resources.db.params.charset = utf8` to your app.ini

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just put "charset" key with desired value into config and DB-driver will execute an appropriate query (depending on DBMS used). It seems to be that currently (version 1.10.5) almost all drivers support that.