# Special characters incorrectly stored in Database (such as ©)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, fonts, character-encoding

I have created a web admin tool with the Zend framework that updates text on a website. The problem is that when "©" is entered in the admin tool, the database stores "Â©". When I go to re-edit the text in the admin tool only "©" is displayed as normal, but when I read the text in other situations "Â©" is read from the database. For example PhpMyAdmin shows "Â©", as do Flash textFields displaying the content.

I use the Zend Framework/PHP/MySQL. Collation is set to `utf8_bin` in MySQL and content type on the admin tool pages is set as follows: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

With in the bootstrap.php file:
    $view->doctype('HTML5');
    $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');

If it shows "testÂ©" in the database "test©" is displayed in the admin tool. If I paste "text©" directly into the database, the data is displayed as blank in the admin tool.

I need the data in the database to match what I see inside the admin tool. If I submit "test©" I don't want it to be stored as "testÂ©"

Comment: what collation are your database tables' configured to use? make sure your connection is using utf8 as well

Comment: You led me to the answer. Setting "resources.db.params.charset = utf8" in the app.ini file fixed the problem. Also found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216864/zend-db-and-encoding